# Is There a Way to Force Lid State to Open

Tags: keyboard, power-management, suspend

My Lenovo X1 Carbon Laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 has a problem where the screen and keyboard stopped working. It *does* work if I use an external monitor and keyboard.

I think the reason for this is that my laptop always thinks the lid is closed, even when it's not. I can see this when I look in the `/proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state` file.

Since I don't know how to fix my laptop, does anyone know of a way to force the lid state to open.

Comment: Was the switch that reads the lid state in your laptop broken?

Comment: go to settings(from external monitor) then go to power management and then select `Do nothing` option for `when lid is closed` option.. and reboot! check if this helps?

Comment: @CharlesGreen, probably. I'm saying that if that's the case, then how do I force the laptop to think the lid is open in the software i.e. ignore the state reported by the hardware.

Comment: @Nullpointer, unfortunately that does not work. I already had it set like that. I believe that, luckily, this is what is allowing me to run the laptop like normal with an external monitor/keyboard -- whether or not the lid is closed.

I assume that the monitor/keyboard is disabled for power saving reasons (if the lid is "closed" then there would be no point in powering them up, even if the laptop is on).